# Why Assert.Equal two different JObject(Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject) got pass

Tags: c#, json.net, xunit

I am quite new to c#, xUnit as well as Newtonsoft.Json. While I am trying compare two different JOject using Assert.Equal() method in unit test, it pass, refer to the below example code

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace TestProject1
{
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [Fact]
        public void Test1()
        {
            JObject jobj1 = JObject.FromObject(new { foo = "bar" });
            JObject jobj2 = JObject.FromObject(new { foo = 1 });
            JObject jobj3 = JObject.FromObject(new { foo = "b" });
            Assert.Equal(jobj1, jobj2); // output: pass
            Assert.Equal(jobj1, jobj3); // output: failure
            Assert.True(jobj1.Equals(jobj2)); // output: failure
            Assert.True(jobj1.Equals(jobj3)); // output: failure
        }
    }
}
```

I don't quite understand how this happens, should I look deep into xUnit or Newtonsoft.Json?

I find there is a [DeepEquals method](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeepEquals.htm) from Newtonsoft.Json, but I am not sure which comparator does xUnit call.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is kind of a bug of xUnit asserts + Newtonsoft Json.NET. The reason is two-fold:

- From Newtonsoft side:

  - `JToken` (base type for "everything" in the library) implements `IEnumerable`
  - `JValue` implements `IComparable` (and `IEnumerable` because it inherits from `JToken`) which throws when two `JValue`s are incompatible
- From xUnit side - if type implements `IComparable` and comparer throws error, [the error is ignored](https://github.com/xunit/assert.xunit/blob/5c8c10e085eb42f39f2fe0b40c94bf56649eb0a4/Sdk/AssertEqualityComparer.cs#L74), then if type implements `IEnumerable` it is treated as a collection and `JValue` is an empty collection, so as collections they are equal

Minimal repro looks like:

```cs
[Fact]
public void Test2()
{
    var jvLeft = JToken.FromObject(1);
    var jvRight = JToken.FromObject("bar");

    // some "debug" checks
    Assert.True(jvLeft is JValue);
    Assert.Empty(jvLeft);
    Assert.Throws<FormatException>(() => (jvRight as IComparable).CompareTo(jvLeft));

    Assert.Equal(jvRight, jvLeft); // output: pass
}
```

One of the fixes is to use `Assert.StrictEqual` (works correctly for `JValue`s only):

```cs
[Fact]
public void Test2()
{
    var jvLeft = JToken.FromObject(1);
    var jvRight = JToken.FromObject("bar");
    Assert.StrictEqual(jvRight, jvLeft); // output: fail
}
```

Or use/follow up with the `JToken.DeepEquals` (as you have discovered):

```cs
[Fact]
public void Test12()
{
    JObject jobj1 = JObject.FromObject(new { foo = "bar" });
    JObject jobj2 = JObject.FromObject(new { foo = 1 });
    Assert.Equal(jobj1, jobj2); // output: pass
    Assert.True(JToken.DeepEquals(jobj1, jobj2)); // output: fail
}
```

Notes:

- This [discussion](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/2063) from the github can be useful.
- JIC [reported a bug](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/2713)